# Stripe Add CreditCard ID response is different from Dashboard

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe.net

Currently using Stripe Test Mode I add a credit card using [this](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards). The card is added successfully to Stripe Dashboard. But when I was looking closer, the *card id* returned by the `'stripeResponseHandler'` is different to what it is set on the Stripe Dashboard.
What was written to Stripe Dashboard:

```
Card ID: card_19FxJYDJ3JQRgrDjabcdELef
```

What the stripeResponseHandler actually returned:

```
Card ID: card_19FxJYDJ3JQRgrDjcOlENnWX
```

I used different testing credit card numbers and no errors are apparently returned, same behavior. What can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. You shouldn't worry about the card ID you receive in the `stripeResponseHandler` callback in your frontend code. In the vast majority of cases, all you need to do in the callback is get the *token* ID (`"tok_..."`) and send it to your backend code so it can be used in an API request, e.g. to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or [a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).